# Django / Python POST API without Model/Serializer

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, post

I want to create a very simple API, with only one endpoint.
I want to send to an API a json like :
{"provider" : "com.facebook.orca",
"code" : "1",
"color" : "#FFFFF"
}

Then, I want to use a python library to control a device in my room(python-yeelight). I want to use this with a Auth token or a username/password authenticate.

What I found on Django Rest Framework was way too complicated for what I need(which is accepting a POST and returning a "success" or "failure" message.

Thank you!

Comment: OK. So where are you having problems doing this in basic Django?

Comment: I need to create a model, a serializer, some fields, meta, etc. All of which are not needed. But I still need the Auth(can't use csrf_token)

Comment: I don't understand that reply. You've said you don't want to use django-rest-framework, which is fine; so you *don't* need to create any of those things. So, what have you actually done, and what problem are you having?

Comment: Because without that framework I don't know how to use basic Auth / Auth key. Django uses crsf token by default, which I cannot use.

Comment: But CSRF has *nothing whatsoever* to do with authentication, so I don't know why you are mentioning it.

Comment: Try making a Post to a basic view (index from the tutorial). It will tell you that there is an invalid crsf token. You can use crsf exempt, but I would like some way of basic Auth.

Comment: You really don't need Auth, but you DO need sessions. But... you need to strip `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` from the MIDDLEWARE section and `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` from `TEMPLATES => OPTIONS => context_processors` in your settings file. Just been through this on an Raspberry PI 3B.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method decorator to implement basic authentication. Wrap all your django views using this decorator.

```
def token_required(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        auth_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN')
        if auth_token:
            try:
                token = Tokens.objects.get(token=auth_token)
                user = token.user
            except Tokens.DoesNotExist:
                user=None
        else:
            r = {
                    'status': -1,
                    'message': 'Please provide a valid token.'
                }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(r), content_type="application/json")
        if user:
            request.user = user
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            r = {
                        'status': -2,
                        'message': 'User not Authorised, Please login'
                }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(r), content_type="application/json")
    return wrap
```

Now all your requests must contain a header as shown below to views wrapped by this decorator to detect the user inside views.

AUTHORIZATION-TOKEN : some_token_value

Your tokens model will look something like as shown below.

```
class Tokens(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="tokens",null=False)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.token is None or self.token == "":
            import uuid
            self.token=uuid.uuid4().hex
        super(Tokens, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Sample use of decorator:

```
@csrf_exempt
@token_required
def your_view(request):
    pass
```

I guess this should help you out.

Comment: I will try it, thank you. Where should I place the custom function? In views.py is it OK?

Comment: Yeah. It will be inside your views.py file.

Comment: Ok, I copied the whole code. How exactly do I pass the username / password in the POST? From the code it seems that I should pass in Headers the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN.
But how do I obtain that? (I am sorry, I am used to PHP / Laravel, first time with Django)